# How can I deploy a set of pages easily in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a site for a business which is going to start selling franchises. Each new franchise will need a set of about 10 pages - one parent page and 9 child pages - that will create a sub-site for that franchise.

When I have installed Woocommerce in Wordpress one step in that process has been to click a link which causes the default WooCommerce Pages to be automagically installed into the site.

How can I replicate this? Google isn't helping me and I didn't see anything in a search here. How can I create a set of generic franchise pages so that the site owner can click a link such as "Create new Franchise" and have those 10 pages be autmoatically added to the Wordpress dashboard?

Thanks.

Comment: What you are looking to do is to create a plugin for a 1-click solution.  You would use wp insert post and set the page type as "page". https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: This looks super promising. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress export into xml and then import will might work?

So you will have a sample site with all default content then create .xml from it which can be then imported to any new WordPress site with all pages and sub pages intact and site ready to go with the default content.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen

Comment: This is a good idea I hadn't thought of. This might work as a temporary solution while I work on the one click plugin suggestion above. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Good luck William!